# How do I Encrypt/Decrypt using GnuPG/GPG4Win from a website?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, gnupg

I am attempting to encrypt/decrypt user names to pass between two different websites using gpg4win 2.1.0. I can get my code to work on my development machine, but not in production.

I'm developing the application with VS 2008.

I have run the GPG4Win install package, chose gnupg & kleopatra.

I've attempted to use the code found at "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/gnupgdotnet.aspx".

I keep getting Error Code 255 Unknown error.

The following code sample is how the GPG application is being run. The `BuildOptions()` function returns the string:

`--homedir "C:\Path\gnupg" --no-auto-check-trustdb --always-trust --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring "C:\Path\gnupg\secring.gpg" --keyring "C:\Path\gnupg\pubring.gpg" --yes --batch --encrypt --armor --recipient recipient@email.ca --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose`

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string inputText, out string outputText)
{
  outputText = "";

  string gpgOptions = BuildOptions();
  string gpgExecutable = GetGpgPath();
  binddirectory = GetGPGInstallLocation();

  // TODO check existence of _bindirectory and gpgExecutable

  // Create startinfo object

  ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(gpgExecutable, gpgOptions);
  pInfo.WorkingDirectory = _bindirectory;
  pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  // Redirect everything: 
  // stdin to send the passphrase, stdout to get encrypted message, stderr in case of errors...
  pInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  _processObject = Process.Start(pInfo);

  // Send pass phrase, if any
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_passphrase))
  {
    _processObject.StandardInput.WriteLine(_passphrase);
    _processObject.StandardInput.Flush();
  }

  // Send input text
  _processObject.StandardInput.Write(inputText);
  _processObject.StandardInput.Flush();
  _processObject.StandardInput.Close();

  _outputString = "";
  _errorString = "";

  // Create two threads to read both output/error streams without creating a deadlock
  ThreadStart outputEntry = new ThreadStart(StandardOutputReader);
  Thread outputThread = new Thread(outputEntry);
  outputThread.Start();
  ThreadStart errorEntry = new ThreadStart(StandardErrorReader);
  Thread errorThread = new Thread(errorEntry);
  errorThread.Start();

  if (_processObject.WaitForExit(ProcessTimeOutMilliseconds))
  {
     // Process exited before timeout...
     // Wait for the threads to complete reading output/error (but use a timeout!)
     if (!outputThread.Join(ProcessTimeOutMilliseconds/2))
       outputThread.Abort();

     if (!errorThread.Join(ProcessTimeOutMilliseconds/2))
       errorThread.Abort();
  }
  else
  {
    // Process timeout: PGP hung somewhere... kill it (as well as the threads!)
    _outputString = "";
    _errorString = "Timed out after " + ProcessTimeOutMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds";
    _processObject.Kill();
    if (outputThread.IsAlive)
      outputThread.Abort();

    if (errorThread.IsAlive)
      errorThread.Abort();
  }

  // Check results and prepare output
  _exitcode = _processObject.ExitCode;
  if (_exitcode == 0)
    outputText = _outputString;
  else
  {
    if (_errorString == "")
    {
      _errorString = "GPGNET: [" + _processObject.ExitCode.ToString() + "]: Unknown error";
    }
    throw new GnuPGException(_errorString);
  }
}
```

Comment: is that an exception in your code or from the errorout of the gnupg executable?

Comment: It is from the error out of the gnupg executable. The error message that is displayed is "GPGNET: [255]: Unknown error".

Comment: I believe my problem has something to do with the account the website is running under and not having access to the keyring folder. The application pool is running under the Network Service identity. If I change it to run under my user account, then everything works as I expect it should.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by creating a user for the app pool identity to run as and set the necessary permissions to access the keyring/gpg program.